# PHP ChatRoom. Username is not showing, only messages

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, apache

I'm trying to make a Chat Room using PHP ( It is working BTW ), but only the messages are displaying, not their usernames. I have created the Databases for them, username and msg. I don't know why their usernames aren't displaying

```js
<? php

//$uname = $_REQUEST['uname'];
//$msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];

$uname = (isset($_REQUEST['uname']) ? $_REQUEST['uname'] : '');
$msg = (isset($_REQUEST['msg']) ? $_REQUEST['msg'] : null);





$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('chatbox', $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO logs (`username` , `msg`) VALUES ('$uname', '$msg')");

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");

while ($extract = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  echo "<span class = 'uname'>".$extract['username'].
  "</span>: <span class = 'msg'> ".$extract['msg'].
  "</span><br/>";
}

?>
```

```css
<?php $con=mysql_connect('localhost',
'root',
'');
 mysql_select_db('chatbox',
$con);
 $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");
 while($extract=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  echo"<span class = 'uname'>" . $extract['username'] ."</span>: <span class = 'msg'> " . $extract['msg'] ."</span><br/>";
}
?>
```

```html
<?php ?>

<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    body {
      padding-right: 250px;
      padding-left: 250px;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: darkkhaki;
    }
    textarea {
      resize: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: #efefef;
    }
    a {
      background-color: cadetblue;
      padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }
    a:hover {
      background-color: chartreuse;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form1">
    Enter your Username
    <input type="text" name="uname">
    <br/>Enter your Message
    <br/>
    <textarea name="msg"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href="#" onclick="">Send</a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="chatlogs">
      Loading Chat...
    </div>
  </form>

  <script>
    function submitChat() {
      if (form1.uname.value == '' || form1.msg.value == '') {
        alert('Please Input Username and Message');
        return;
      }

      var uname = form1.uname.value;
      var msg = form1.msg.value;
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }

      xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php?uname' + uname + '&msg=' + msg, true);
      xmlhttp.send();

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

. Feel free to point out the mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
insert.php?uname
```

with

```
insert.php?uname=
```

Updated Code:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php?uname=' + uname + '&msg=' + msg, true);
```

You are not inserting uname